# .Formula code run-time error 1004

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

The following code returns the above error

```
Dim RAWfRange As Range
Dim Loc1 As Range

Set Loc1 = Range("F1")

Set RAWfRange = Range(Loc1, Loc1.End(xlDown))

Loc1.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Report!B:O,14,FALSE),"")" ' <--- Error on this line
Loc1.AutoFill Destination:=RAWfRange
```

Any idea why? I have similar codes to this in the same macro but this particular one won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double up quotes within a quoted string.

```
Loc1.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Report!B:O,14,FALSE),"""")"
```

There is also an alternate to `""`.

```
Loc1.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Report!B:O,14,FALSE),TEXT(,))"
```